# Getting only first *part* of a file from HTTP request for pre-compiled asset from Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, http, passenger

I'm working in a web app, and occasionally a user reports that the main javascript file has arrived at their browser incompletely. The last few hundred lines are missing. The browser tries to execute the script, and of course, it results in an error.

A hard refresh fixes the problem. This is known only to happen in production, where the javascript files are all pre-compiled and served as static assets. (Each app server is taken off the node balancer during the time that its static assets get pre-compiled.)

*This application is running Ruby on  Rails v4.0.1 + Passenger 4.0.53 + Apache 2.4*. The problematic request is `/assets/application-VERSION.js`.

How does the file get treated as if it's complete when it isn't? Could it be Passenger that is making the mistake? Or the browser? Or something else?